# Reply with unsupported protocol when writing custom network stack

Tags: networking, network-programming, protocols, wifi

I have been writing my own version of the 802.11 protocol with network stack. This is mostly a learning experience to see more in depth on how networks work.

My question is, is there a standard for replying to client devices that a certain protocol is unsupported?

I have an android device connecting to my custom wifi device and immediately sending a TON of requests at the DNS port of my UDP protocol. Since I would like to test out other protocols I would very much like a way for my wifi device to tell the android device that DNS is not available and get it to quite down a little.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an idea why the device tries to talk DNS with your device. I guess that most people with security in mind will recommend not to send an answer at all so that it looks as if the device is not existing, especially in case of requests from WAN.

Comment: Is that the only connection the Android device would have?

Comment: @mm759 I believe its trying to talk to DNS to determine if the wifi the android device is connected to has an internet connection.

Comment: @rodolk I dont know what you mean only connection. It is the only wifi connection it has. It is a tablet so no cell connection is available.

Comment: Is your device an access point in a infrastructure-setup or a device in an ad-hoc-setup?

Comment: My expectation concerning an IP4-device is that it tries to find a DNS-server using DHCP.

Comment: Its setup to be in infrastructure-setup. This spamming of DNS port happens after DHCP setup. Although maybe there is an option in the DHCP standard that is supposed help with this.

Comment: You shouldn't reply at all. Just a further waste of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a possibility to send a reply that a service is not available.

I can't find anything about this case in the [UDP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc768).

One [part of the DNS specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) assumes that there are multiple DNS servers and defines how to handle communication with them. This explains part of the behavior in your network, but does not provide much information how to handle it.

4.2.1 Messages - format - UDP usage

> The optimal UDP retransmission policy will vary with performance of the
> Internet and the needs of the client, but the following are recommended:

> - The client should try other servers and server addresses
>   before repeating a query to a specific address of a server.

> - The retransmission interval should be based on prior
>   statistics if possible.  Too aggressive retransmission can
>   easily slow responses for the community at large.  Depending
>   on how well connected the client is to its expected servers,
>   the minimum retransmission interval should be 2-5 seconds.

7.2 Resolver Implementation - sending the queries

> - If a resolver gets a server error or other bizarre response
>   from a name server, it should remove it from SLIST, and may
>   wish to schedule an immediate transmission to the next
>   candidate server address.

According to this you could try to send garbage back to the client, but this is rather a hack, or an error, but how does an error look like? Such a solution assumes that you have knowledge about the service that you don't support.

I believe that the DNS - requests can be avoided by using [DHCP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol). DHCP allows to specify DNS-servers as listed in the linked page. This is the usual way that I know for a DNS-resolver in a LAN to get initial DNS servers although I don't find anything about this in the DNS specification. You can give the Android -  device a DNS-server with DHCP so that it does to need to try to query your device. Querying your device could be a fallback.

Additionally to DNS there is [mDNS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) which uses multicasts in the network to send queries. This seems not to be the protocol you have to do with because it uses the special port 5353.

Comment: I read through the specifications and I believe these are the best solutions available. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to stop DNS in the way you intend. However, **only for your tests** you can check the UDP messages and find out the names the device is looking for. Then you update the hosts file (google how to do it: http://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/) and add those names with some localoop IP address. That might work for your test.
Other possibility is to change DNS server to some localloop IP address: http://xslab.com/2013/08/how-to-change-dns-settings-on-android/ 
Again, this is only to avoid having all the DNS messages through the wifi connection.